# Why Tap Gesture Recognizer to dismiss keyboard has Referencing Outlet Collection gestureRecognizers-View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboard, iboutletcollection

The purpose of my Tap Gesture Recognizer is to dismiss the keyboard if the user touches any part of the screen outside the keyboard.

The Tap Gesture Recognizer has a referencing outlet collection named gestureRecognizer connected to the root View of the View Controller. I don't know why this is necessary or how to use Referencing Outlet Collections in general. I'm very curious why this is necessary for my Tap Gesture Recognizer. I do not see any code related to the gestureRecognizer in my .h or .m files for the ViewController.

I found the code for this Tap Gesture Recognizer from a tutorial out there on the interwebz so I don't know exactly why they programmed it the way they did. Would really like to know.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any code for the gesture recognizer in my ViewController's .m or .h files. The only code I can find is in the Storyboard. If I right-click the Tap Gesture Recognizer, I see a gestureRecognizers-View in Referencing Outlet Collections. I'm thinking this might be related to making a collection of touch points available for the entire root view of the ViewController?